# How to create trigger on database that 'triggers' when mirroring role changes from mirror to principal

Tags: sql-server

I want to perform some sql when my database mirroring state changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an [event notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx) for the [Database Mirroring State Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191502%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). See [Implementing Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178080%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for how to design a service that processes the notification and does whatever is appropriate. Keep in mind that event notifications are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using SQL Server alerts, which can trigger a job after the WMI event occurs.

Your WMI Query in this case will be

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE_MIRRORING_STATE_CHANGE
```

More details (and scripts): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966392.aspx